# how to manipulate CAD documents

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, cad

I am working On a WebMapping Project using Silverlight (c#).  I am looking for ways to read and display CAD documents (.STEP  , .iges , .brep ,  .dxf). Is there any library to do that  ?

Comment: For DXF there's [CadLib](https://www.woutware.com/cadlib/4.0/silverlight5)

Comment: Take a look to [Eyeshot](http://www.devdept.com) for STEP and IGES.

Comment: yes but i need Free tools  .  thank you for your answers